# Unmount Drive without Deleting AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

How should I unmount a drive well ensuring it wont be deleted? We want to move

```
vol-0de12fb88020aa624
from i-0b727a35caea24013 
to i-0dff0911c0ebf45f9
```

I want to move the volume, do not want copy files from one EBS volume to another EBS volume ?? How fast can unmounting result in deleting of the volume?
can anyone advice me with the best way for this ?

Comment: Unmounting a drive won't erase the contents. How you do it depends on what operating system you're using.

Comment: Is this the root volume, or an extra data volume? Best approach is to shutdown both instances, detach the volume, reattach to the new instance, and start up.